# Replacing few different characters in a string

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

I try to replace few characters in some string  `14/04/2010 17:12:11` and get, for example, next result:

```
14%04%2010%17%12%11
```

I know about method `Replace`, but its definition looks like `Replace(Char,Char)`. Which means using it 3 times in method chain. Doesn't look idiomatic. How to solve the problem in an optimal way? Regular expressions? Any ways to escape them?

Comment: Note: `Replace` also as a constructor like this: `Replace(String, String)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chain it:

```
string s1 = "14/04/2010 17:12:1";

string s2 = s1.Replace("/","%").Replace(" ","%").Replace(":","%");
```

Comment: Please note that instead of the suggested you could use string s2 = s1.Replace('/','%').Replace(' ','%').Replace(':#,'%'); (note I replaced "" with '') for MUCH better performance! In fact this will be much faster than the regex variant, too.

Answer (score 8):

```
Regex.Replace(myString, "[/ :]", "%");
```

Simple, yet elegant!

Comment: Is there a simple way without using regular expressions?

Comment: Do you need to pass the input string as the first parameter?

Comment: Regular expressions are the simple way.

Comment: As you pointed out the only other simple method is calling Replace three times -- myStr = myStr.Replace('/', '%').Replace(' ', '%').Replace(':', '%');

Comment: Looks good now.  I can't imagine how many lines of code regex has saved me from typing!

Answer (score 0):

An alternate `Regex` approach, although I disagree with the use of it here. This simply replaces any non-numeric characters:

```
string date2 = Regex.Replace(date1, @"\D", "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do it often, write a method:

```
static string Replace(string s, string c, char n)
{            
    for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
        s = s.Replace(c[i], n);            
    return s;
}
```

e.g.

```
string s1 = "14/04/2010 17:12:11";                
string s2 = Replace(s1, "/ :", '%'));
```